# Algorithm to implement non-binary trees using 1-dimensional vector?

Tags: algorithm

Each node of the tree might have an arbitrary number of children.
I need a way to construct and traverse such trees, but to implement them using one dimensional vector or a list.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the values of the nodes?

Comment: @Juliano I wish.. My homework days are long gone :)
@danben No restriction.

Comment: Any tree can be transformed into a binary tree (and back into its original form). The transformed binary tree has, for every node, a linked list of its original children as first child, and the pointer to the next sibling in as the second child.

Comment: Can you give some background? Why do you need to do this? Perhaps we can better help by backing up a step.

Comment: Does it truly *have* to have an arbitrary number of children?  There is a simple solution if we can restrict the maximum number of children to a node (though it will take up more and more memory the larger that max is; the only reason to do this would be to make obtaining a specific node O(1); otherwise, the memory tradeoff is probably not worth it)

Comment: @BlueRaja And this solution is ?

Comment: You store each node in the position of the array where it WOULD be in a full n-ary tree.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Ahnentafel_list - that link is for binary trees, but it is not difficult to extend that to n-ary trees.

Comment: I can make that an answer if this is what you truly wanted, but I'd feel dirty - the reason no one does this is that you (almost?) never need both random-access and random-inserts into the data-structure; and if you need one or the other, just use an array or a tree.  Why do you need both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only can use one vector (not specified in question), and Nodes should not contain it's own list, only some pointers (addresses in vector), then you can try this:

1. each node holds address of its sibling
2. first node after given (if it is not its sibling) is child, with pointer to second child and so on
3. each of its child has it's own children

So for tree like this:

```
A
| \
B  E ___
|\  \ \ \
C D  F G H
```

Your vector would look like:

```
idx:    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
nodes:  A B C D E F G H
next:   _ 4 3 _ _ 6 7 _
```

where `_` is null pointer

*Edit:*
Another approach:

1. every node holds address of region in vector occupied by its children
2. children are next to each other
3. there exists null node in vector, marking end of siblings group

For that approach given tree would look like:

```
idx:    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B
nodex:  A _ B E _ C D _ F G H _
child:  2   5 8   _ _   _ _ _
```

That way you can easily find children of any randomly given node and reorganize array without moving all elements (just copy children to end of table, update pointer and add next child to end of table)

Comment: Doesn't that make E the child of D in your example, then?

Comment: @danben Only if you try to traverse from any randomly node. If you go from root (index 0), then it should not be possible. It's not ideal, by it was my first guess after seeing this question

Comment: Ok, I see.  I still think the OP wanted a single list, though - otherwise you could just have one list per sibling group and be done with it.

Comment: @danben It is single list, but i printed it in 2 rows to show item and next_pointer. It should be record/struct/whatever, or 2 vectors, one for item, one for pointer (same size, and probably same memory consumption as with record)

Comment: Hmm.. The second approach seems reasonable, (and accurate hopefully) Traversing recursively such a tree would be easy I think.

Comment: In the second approach, you can save indexes of "to,from" for each node instead of saving blanks.

Comment: The two approaches in this answer are duals. To represent an n-ary tree you need at least two links: firstChild and nextSibling. (They're available in DOM trees, and also in the Inform 6 text adventure programming environment: http://www.inform-fiction.org/manual/html/s3.html#s3_2 .) You can either store both links in every node, or store just one and let the sequence of the vector encode the other.

Comment: If you store nextSibling and encode firstChild via ordering, your vector is a depth-first walk of the tree. If you store firstChild and encode nextSibling via ordering, your vector is a breadth-first walk of the tree. But either way, any edit is going to be a huge pain. Storing both links seems easiest.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of storing a full binary tree in an array (as is used for binary heap implementations) is nice because you can represent the tree with an array of elements in the order of a level-order tree traversal. Using that scheme, there are quick tricks for computing the parent and child node positions. Moving to a tree in which each node can have an arbitrary number of elements throws a wrench into that kind of scheme.

There are, however, several schemes for representing arbitrary trees as binary trees. They are discussed in great detail in Donald Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*, Volume I, Section 2.3.

If the nodes themselves are permitted to contain a pointer, you could store a list of child indicies for each node. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: This problem would be much easier if the trees were binary.  But your answer boils down to "Go read Knuth" which isn't so helpful.

Comment: The helpful part of my answer is to note that all trees can be represented as binary trees, which is not necessarily obvious, and to provide a source of schemes for doing that. There are many and which will work best will depend on the OP's requirements.

Comment: "Go read Knuth" is an answer to most of life's problems. Except maybe human relationships.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically do is write the beginnings of a memory manager for a Lisp interpreter by pairing off the vector's elements into cons cells.  Here is such a thing I threw together in C just now:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE 1024
#define NIL 0
#define IVAL_MASK 0x8000000

struct pair
{
    bool allocated;
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};

size_t allocate_pair(struct pair vector[])
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < MEMORY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (not vector[i].allocated)
                {
                    vector[i].allocated = true;
                    return i;
                }
        }

    return NIL;
}

size_t make_pair(struct pair vector[], size_t a, size_t b)
{
    size_t the_pair = allocate_pair(vector);

    if (the_pair != NIL)
        {
            vector[the_pair].first = a;
            vector[the_pair].second = b;
            return the_pair;
        }
    else
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Out of pairs -- make_pair(%p, %zu, %zu)",
                    vector,
                    a,
                    b);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

size_t first(struct pair vector[], size_t index)
{
    assert(vector[index].allocated);

    return vector[index].first;
}


size_t second(struct pair vector[], size_t index)
{
    assert(vector[index].allocated);

    return vector[index].second;
}

void print_pair_aux(struct pair[], size_t, size_t);
void print_pair(struct pair vector[], size_t p)
{
    assert(vector[p].allocated);

    size_t a = first(vector, p);
    size_t b = second(vector, p);

    printf("(");

    print_pair_aux(vector, a, b);

    printf(")");
}

void print_pair_aux(struct pair vector[], size_t a, size_t b)
{
    if (a == NIL)
        printf("NIL");
    else if (a >= IVAL_MASK)
        printf("%zu", a &~ IVAL_MASK);
    else
        print_pair(vector, a);

    if (b == NIL)
        printf("");
    else if (b >= IVAL_MASK)
        printf(" . %zu", b &~ IVAL_MASK);
    else
        {
            printf(" ");
            print_pair_aux(vector,
                           first(vector, b),
                           second(vector, b));
        }

}

int main(void) 
{
    struct pair *vector = calloc(MEMORY_SIZE, sizeof *vector);

#define cons(A,B) make_pair(vector, (A), (B))
#define ival(x) ((x) | IVAL_MASK)

    size_t a = cons(ival(3), cons(ival(4), NIL));
    size_t b = cons(ival(2), cons(a, NIL));
    size_t c = cons(ival(6), cons(ival(7), cons(ival(8), NIL)));
    size_t d = cons(ival(5), cons(c, NIL));
    size_t e = cons(ival(1), cons(b, cons(d, NIL)));

    print_pair(vector, e);
    puts("");
}
```

```
$ cc -std=c99 try.c
$ ./a.out
(1 (2 (3 4)) (5 (6 7 8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using one dimensional linked list with little overhead.

Every parent will contain pointers to its children.(But this requires deciding if the max number of nodes are know before hand).

For a tree having A as root node and B,C,D as children its representation will be as below.

A -> B
A -> C
A -> D

Note that there are 3 links from A.

One way to overcome the upperlimit on the number of nodes is having additional pointer in the nodes.

So, now A ->(child) B ->(adj) ->(adj) C ->(adj) -> D

In this case, its quite complex to update the tree, when deletion occurs.

Its even easier to design better data structures if you could tell your time bounds on the various operations.

Answer (score 0):

With no restrictions on the values of the nodes, and assuming you can use only a single list, I would construct it as follows:

Represent each node as `( val ; [ int ; ...] )` where val is the node's value and each int is the position in the list of one of it's children.  Use a non-printable separator if necessary.

Traversal is very slow.